# Matplotlib missing patches in graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I need to create a heatmap from a csv file and highlight some cells, my idea was to create a mask from a Panda's dataframe and then iterate through the mask and add a patch each time.
Unfortunately even if the mask seems to work correctly only two patches are placed instead of the 4 I would like to have, does anyone know why?

```
df = pd.read_csv(argv[1])
df = df.transpose()
mask = df == 3

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = sns.heatmap(df, ax=ax)

for row in range(df.shape[0]):
 for col in range(df.shape[1]):
    if mask[col][row]:
        ax.add_patch(Rectangle((row, col), 1, 1))

plt.show()
```

The obtained graph:

[image: This is the graph I'm obtaining right now]

Comment: Could you share you df or a sample of it?

Comment: Yes sorry, I'm using this [csv](https://pastebin.com/raw/iZkEJ6a6), the resulting df is the [following](https://pastebin.com/raw/8XCvQUPB)

Answer (score 0):

After trying, you need to change the order of your indices when you create the rectangles:

```
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
df = pd.DataFrame([[3,0,0],
[2,3,0],
[1,2,0],
[3,1,0],
[2,0,3],
[1,0,2],
[0,0,1],
[0,0,0]], columns = ["reg1","reg2","reg3"])

mask = df == 3

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = sns.heatmap(df, ax=ax)
for row in range(df.shape[0]):
    for col in range(df.shape[1]):
        if mask.iloc[row,col]:
            ax.add_patch(Rectangle((col, row), 1, 1, fill=False, edgecolor='blue', lw=3))
            
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]